# System tray icon without widgets

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm wondering if there's a way to implement system tray icon + menu functionality without widgets module?

Comment: A quick search: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-overview.html#taskbar

Comment: thanks, but not sure if i understand how it helps here. What i need is something like QSystemTrayIcon but without widgets module dependency.  Or/and some ideas about approach on how to implement it optimal way.

Comment: Sorry, mixed *SystemTry* and *TaskBar*

Comment: You should write `QSystemTrayIcon` wrapper in C++ to use it in QML. There is no way to create system tray icon in pure QML.

Answer (score 11):

Qt 5.8 introduces a [`SystemTrayIcon`](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qml-qt-labs-platform-systemtrayicon.html) QML type in the experimental Qt Labs Platform module, as part of the Qt Quick Controls 2 offering. It uses a native implementation directly from the Qt Platform Abstraction layer where available, and Qt Widgets as a fallback on other platforms.

Comment: Still requires Qt Widgets at least for Windows

Comment: The Windows port of Qt has gained support for native menus in Qt 5.10, which made it also possible to move QSystemTrayIcon's Windows-backend from Qt Widgets to to the Qt Platform Abstraction layer. Thus, starting with Qt 5.10, Qt Labs Platform SystemTrayIcon and Menu no longer requires Qt Widgets on Windows. Furthermore, Qt Labs MenuBar becomes functional on Windows.