# qml systemtrayicon without qwidget/qapplication?

Tags: qt, qml

The last post here seems to imply that systemtrayicon no longer requires qwidget or qapplication... [System tray icon without widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095630/system-tray-icon-without-widgets)

Ive given this a try and its not working for me. Am I correct in guessing this is an incorrect statement?

Put the sample code bellow and import.

in main.qml:

```
SystemTrayIcon {
        visible: true
        //icon.source: "qrc:/images/tray-icon.png"

        onActivated: {
            window.show()
            window.raise()
            window.requestActivate()
        }
}
```

Error: QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication

Answer (score 1):

**TL; DR;** No, you have misunderstood. [`SystemTrayIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-systemtrayicon.html) needs you to use [`QApplication`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html).

---

**Explanation:**

[`SystemTrayIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-systemtrayicon.html) is a [`QSystemTrayIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html) wrapper that can be used in QML and therefore it is necessary to use [`QApplication`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html), and that is indicated in [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-systemtrayicon.html#availability):

> #### Availability
>
> A native system tray icon is currently available on the following
>   platforms:
>
> - All window managers and independent tray implementations for X11 that implement the freedesktop.org XEmbed system tray specification.
> - All desktop environments that implement the freedesktop.org D-Bus StatusNotifierItem specification, including recent versions of KDE and
>     Unity.
> - All supported versions of macOS. Note that the Growl notification system must be installed for showMessage() to display messages on OS X
>     prior to 10.8 (Mountain Lion).
>
> The Qt Labs Platform module uses Qt
>   Widgets as a fallback on platforms that do not have a native
>   implementation available. **Therefore, applications that use types from
>   the Qt Labs Platform module should link to QtWidgets and use
>   QApplication instead of QGuiApplication.**
>
> To link against the QtWidgets library, add the following to your qmake
>   project file:
>
> ```
> QT += widgets
> ```
>
> Create an instance of QApplication in main():
>
> ```
> #include <QApplication>
> #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
>     QApplication app(argc, argv);
>     QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
>     engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
>     return app.exec();
> }
> ```
>
> Note: Types in Qt.labs modules are not guaranteed to remain compatible
>   in future versions.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>